# JavaFX, can't get icon on the title bar to show up after exporting to *.JAR

Tags: java, javafx, icons

Every time I export my project into *.jar in eclipse I lose all of images in my project (in Eclipse). I've tried to put images directly into the *.jar and it works in some other cases but not this one.

Fragment of code with loading of this icon:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:icon.png"));
```

Comment: Where is the image icon located in your project?

Comment: when it works it is in default (?) folder, the one holding bin, src etc

Comment: Have you tried putting the image in the same folder as the .jar when you run it?

Comment: doesn't work, sadly

Comment: Strange, but anyway. I've posted an answer to hopefully solve your problem. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading the image from the working directory, not the jar itself. This is why it's working in development, and not in production. If you move the image to the same folder as the jar is located it should work, but I'm assuming you want the image to be contained inside your jar file.

Move the image to one of your packages (any, as long as it gets bundled with the jar). Then you need to access the image, use the [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) for this. It looks like you're using javafx, so you can use this to get your image: `primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("the/path/to/your/image.png"));`.

Comment: Works great! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

to work with the files inside the jar, need to use `ZipInputStream` or `JarInputStream`

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. You can use the class loader to load a resources from within the working jar file. You would need the zip/jar streams if you wanted to load the image from another zip/jar file.